# Does the Anaconda installer install things outside of the Anaconda directory?

Tags: python, c++, c++11, installation, anaconda

I'm writing a program in C++ and have successfully implemented Python code in my C++ program. I'm trying to package my software as an exe and dlls to hide source code from my customers.

My program (in exe/dll format) works when I have Anaconda installed, but not when I manually place the necessary files where they would normally be installed (by creating my own Anaconda folder and putting the DLLs and Libs folder there). The PATH variables are constant for both. Are there supplemental things that the Anaconda installer does, like install additional dependencies? I do not want to make my customers install Anaconda to make my package work.

Basically, what do I need to include in my software package to make it stand alone?

UPDATE:

When I have the "Register Anaconda as my default Python 3.7" checked, my program works. However if I install Anaconda with this box unchecked, it does not. What exactly does checking this box do, and what is the best way to include the same functionality in my package?

[image]

Comment: I think this is more or less impossible to answer without knowing what the dependencies of your software are. The answer to the title question (which is different than the question in the body of the post) is yes, because configuration is generally stored in your user directory, and environments *may* be stored there, again depending on your setup.

Comment: Create a conda package for your exe, using the proper `{{ compiler('cxx') }}` build dependencies in your recipe. Then, install it to a prefix: `conda create -yp C:\prefix mypkg`, then add a script.bat in this prefix which sets the proper PATH for all the DLLs that your application needs, in a relative manner, from that prefix. Zip that prefix, send it to customer. Ask customer to launch the script.bat file for launching your software. PATH will comprise a subset of: `%prefix%;%prefix%\scripts;%prefix%\Library\bin;%prefix$\bin;%prefix%\Library\usr\bin;%prefix%\Library\mingw-w64\bin`

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I already have a large application which is being deployed with install shield, so I'm hoping to wrap up the python dependencies using that. Is it possible?